# Question migration to SE sites in beta state

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there any restriction on migration to sites still in beta?

If not, why not add the option to migrate questions to http://robotics.stackexchange.com?

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97579/how-to-attach-wheel-encoder-to-motor) seems to be much more focused on mechanical than electrical, for example.

Comment: Check out [this thread on meta](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/more-migration-options).  It's dedicated to expanding migration options.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about *private* betas, but moderators can migrate questions to any Stack Exchange site, including those in beta. However, this is a manual process. If you see a *good* question that may belong on another site, go ahead and flag the question and let us (the moderators) know.

Based on the number of questions migrated to other sites, it doesn't make sense at this time to add an option to the off-topic close dialogue for any other sites by default.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if the questions can be migrated into *private* betas.  Could the SE community mods chime in on this, please?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Right now it is not possible for *me* to migrate a question to a private beta, and I believe it is strongly discouraged (to allow the beta site to establish itself).

Comment: Well, the policy is what it is.  However, I don't see how migrating questions into a private beta would hamper its ability of getting established.  Betas usually benefit from more questions rather than less.  Besides, the folks who run the private beta can always refuse to accept the migration request, if it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Option to migrate depends on the frequency of the target site, and the mods. If op needs to migrate, or you/other users think it should be migrated to SE x or y, you can either close with "off topic -> other" and add a comment, or flag the post as other (needs mod attention), or both, if the question requires it.

I too think that we should have an option to migrate to DIY or maybe Auto SEs