# Arduino.SE . We've got a live one!

Tags: discussion, arduino

Folks,

It is my pleasure to be the first to post the news that the dedicated [Arduino stack went into public beta](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/).  It's great that persistence is winning.  If at first you don't succeed, try and try again.

Now we have a place where to [migrate](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/question-migration-to-se-sites-in-beta-state) the questions which are too Arduino and not enough EE.

Comment: So, clear questions with preliminary research and an included schematic means it stays here, anything else we migrate. Nice.

Comment: This is great. Hopefully they can stop infesting EE.SE now. Can we set up a filter so that if either "shield" or "sketch" is mentioned together with "arduino" the question automatically gets banished to the new site?

Comment: Haven't they been shut down during beta 3 times?

Comment: @MattYoung  The previous proposal for Arduino.SE was closed in Apr 2013 while it was in *private* beta.  This one seems to have made it to *public* beta.  AFAIK, this is the 6th proposal for Arduino.SE.  I have reasons to hope that it will work out this time.

Comment: I really hope so.

Comment: Maybe we can set up a filter so old cranky people stuck in the 19xx's can only access the Arduino.SE too...

Comment: @Passerby What keywords would you filter then?

Comment: Anyway @nick, mind differentiating what's `too Arduino and not enough EE`?

Comment: @Passerby  I'd be delighted to elaborate on that.  On a technical note however, this warrants a separate thread on Meta, or a chat.  We might as well do it in the [EE.SE mod election chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13239/electrical-engineering-2014-election).

Comment: @OlinLathrop You have always been able to keep questions tagged Arduino or Shield from showing up by using the ignored tags function. Would you like me to set that up for you?

Comment: @W5VO: My not seeing them won't keep them from polluting the site.  I want to see them so that I know it's going on.

Answer (score 6):

Migrating questions to Arduino.SE is not going to be an option for a while. See [this post for more detailed reasoning](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/migration-guidelines).

Comment: Notwithstanding, it's good that we have Arduino.SE now.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I have mixed feelings about that. However, I'm not going to take actions that I believe would hurt the Arduino.SE site or its chances of surviving.

Comment: I will take actions, which will improve Arduino.SE's chances of surviving.

Comment: @NickAlexeev You effort should be towards the best interest of the user asking the question and where he can get a better resolution to his problem. Any migration action or any other kind of action can't be motivated by an effort to keep Arduino.SE alive.