# Arduino question migration

Tags: discussion, arduino

Here's a little idea I'm throwing into the ring for flaming:

How about if any questions with the word "Arduino" in the title automatically get migrated instantly to the Arduino SE?  Even better, they never appear on EE, but go straight to A.SE...?

Comment: This was proposed and hotly debated the moment Arduino.SE went into public beta.  See [comments in this thread](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/3377/7036) (if you haven't seen it already).

Comment: So I'm not alone in my belief that the Arduino oiks have a special level of hell reserved for them.  For them, and for people who talk in theatres.  That's good to know.

Comment: How about we just ban beginners instead? That seems to be what this movement is about

Comment: @W5VO  I was impressed by this recent post on meta.SO : [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256003/279844).  I'm deeply impressed by the references, which it's using : [Why Online Communities Decay Over Time](http://rs.io/2014/02/26/why-online-communities-decay-over-time.html) and [A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](http://www.shirky.com/writings/group_enemy.html).  The latter is long, but it's well worth reading.

Comment: "Special level of hell" does not necessarily equate to "not quite qualified for the level of discussion that EESE tries to maintain".   Whatever the background of the poster, directing people to the best source of help for their problem, or explaining that EESE isn't quite right for their request through moderation tools while maintaining a level of common courtesy isn't an unreasonable approach.

Answer (score 7):

Or even better, you could set up your filters to ignore questions tagged [arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino).

No.

Comment: That assumes that the person posting has the wherewithal to select the right tag - or to even have the slightest clue what a tag is.

Comment: That's simply putting your head in the sand to not see the problems instead of dealing with them.

Comment: That filter is pointless. All it does is make the text lighter so they stick out like a sore thumb.

Comment: @Matt There is an option to either hide them or show them in a lighter color. Go to your user page, click on "Preferences", then look at the "Ignored Tags" section.

Comment: @JYelton Thanks, wish I would have found that option a long time ago.

Comment: @Majenko considering that all new questions require atleast one tag, and Arduino is almost always added as a tag (It's literally the most popular tag on **THIS** SE), that's not a problem.

Answer (score 4):

There are two broad classes of questions on EE.SE that have the [arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino) tag.

The first class is about an issue that is specific to the Arduino HW/SW environment.

The second class is about a more general EE (or embedded systems) issue that just happens to arise in the context of an Arduino project.

As a moderator, I try to figure out which class a new question falls into, and migrate the former to Arduino.SE, and keep the latter in EE.SE.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/101770/7036), which illustrates the class two of the Arduino questions.  That fellow is asking a purely analog question about grounding of thermocouples.  The word "Arduino" can be replaced with "ATMega" or "microcontroller" without any change of meaning.

Answer (score 1):

@Majenko
Aggressive migration of Arduino question was proposed and hotly debated the moment Arduino.SE went into public beta.  See [comments in this thread](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3377/7036) (if you haven't seen it already).

There is a bigger long term underlying problem.  Questions older than 60 days can not be migrated.  All these old threads act like bait for search engines, which attract ardweenie traffic.  There's little we can do about that old bait.
Here's an example: [old thread itself](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48673/rgb-control-via-website), [related meta thread](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3747/7036).  Best viewed with 10k visibility.

At the moment of writing, Arduino.SE has got 650 threads, EE.SE and StackOverflow has got 2,800 and 4,200 threads tagged [arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino) , respectively.  StackOverflow gets the greatest number of new Arduino questions per day.

Users who have accounts on both Arduino.SE and EE.SE are fairly good at predicting which question will work better where.  On the other hand, a lot of new users and infrequent users are not aware that Arduino.SE exists.  They should be enlightened about the existence of Arduino.SE.

Comment: Maybe we should invent the Ardweenie Enlightening Device™

Comment: @Majenko  I saw a product called [Fubarino](http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/node/4854) on your web site.  Is anyone working on a Snafuino (stripped down entry level version of Fubarino) ?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I do have a really really small PIC32 board in the pipeline - samples are with Microchip at the moment for evaluation and demonstration. http://chipkit.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=3132